# Configurable Swatches: Error Processing Request: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Tags: magento-1.9, color-swatches

I have enable Configurable Swatches, but I encounter a problem it shows me a page (There has been an error processing your request) Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 164106845

Here's what my file contains :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:269:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `design_change` AS `main_table` WHERE (store_id = :store_id) AND (date_from <= :required_date or date_from IS NULL) AND (date_to >= :required_date or date_to IS NULL)";i:1;s:2618:"#0 /home/hairqualkn/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/hairqualkn/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/hairqualkn/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/hairqualkn/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/hairqualkn/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Design.php(179): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design.php(62): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Design->loadChange('1', NULL)
#8 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(162): Mage_Core_Model_Design->loadChange('1')
#9 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(124): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_initDesign()
#10 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php(92): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->_loadPart('design')
#11 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(774): Mage_Core_Model_App_Area->load()
#12 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(512): Mage_Core_Model_App->loadArea('frontend')
#13 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#14 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#16 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /home/hairqualkn/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /home/hairqualkn/www/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}";s:3:"url";s:14:"/peruvien.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"fr";}
```

Comment: your issue fixed? and how to fixed this one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Most of the time Mysql goes away because of the low default setting for `max_allowed_packet`. Worth giving it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your reply how to increase?

Comment: Travelest thou to the fine StackOverflow link provided and there thou shalt find thine answer.